# Javascript: High and low peaks of sinusoidal pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to extract all the peaks of a sinusoidal array, meaning all the high and low values. The wave goes constantly up and down, something like this:

```
var wave = [2, 4, 2, -1, -3, -1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 7, 6, 5, 1, 4, 6, 9, 6, 4 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 4];
```

The data in the array is random and can start or stop with anything. A simple comparison with the previous value is not enough, because the next value in the row can be higher or lower. Numbers can be negative or positive.

Comment: Instead of comparing the current value to the previous, try comparing the current value to the previous AND the next. Consider the edges special cases. `cur > prev && cur > next` means peak, `cur < prev && cur < next` means valley. When you have an edge, use the current value to substitute in for the missing value hanging off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect question. A differential is essential. This should do it;

```js
var wave = [2, 4, 2, -1, -3, -1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 7, 6, 5, 1, 4, 6, 9, 6, 4 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 4],
   peaks = wave.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p.concat(c-(a[i-1] || 0)) ,[])
               .reduce((p,c,i,a) => Math.sign(c) !== (Math.sign(a[i+1]) || Math.sign(c)) ? p.concat(i) : p,[])
               .map(e => wave[e]);
console.log(peaks);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following prints out the high and low peaks:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>

    var wave = [2, 4, 2, -1, -3, -1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 7, 6, 5, 1, -4, 6, 9, 6, 4 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 4];

    var high = new Array();
    var low = new Array();
    var asc = false;
    var prev = wave[0];

    for (i = 1; i < wave.length; i++) 
    {
        if (wave[i] > prev && asc == false) {
            asc = true;
            low.push(prev);
        }
        if (wave[i] < prev && asc == true) {
            asc = false;
            high.push(prev);
        }
        prev = wave[i];     
    }

    console.log('Low Values: ' + low.toString()); //Low Values: 2,-3,1,2
    console.log('High Values: ' + high.toString()); //High Values: 4,9,9,5

</script>
</body>
</html>
```